# Query for multiple properties on the same array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.chat.find().pretty().limit(3)
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7662"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 2,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 2"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7663"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 3,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 23"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7664"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 4,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 24"
        }
    ]
}
```

Query needed:
Row count  where "user1" : 1, "capty" : 'B' and "body" : "hiii 1"

I tried:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "user1": 1,  "messages.capty": "B" , "messages.body": "hiii 1" } }
])
```

but this is not working as matches any messages where capty = 'B' or  "messages.body": "hiii 1".

i.e desireable output.
2 (for record1 and record3)

Comment: `db.chat.findOne({"user":1, "message.capty": "B", "message.body" : "hiii 1"})`Ought to work. Why are you aggregating if you are not referencing ?

Comment: @Ozan No it won't the conditions would be considered against "all" array elements without `$elemMatch`, which specifically looks on the current array element for both.

Comment: @NeilLunn In that case my example would return any document that matches has one of the given specifications, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Ozan Read the answer and try it!

Comment: @NeilLunn I created the same db and used the methods and checked them out! You were right! My method doesn't match anything.

Comment: @Ozan Maybe you learned something then and found my answer "helpful". [I think there is an action for that on this site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here. That operator is used for "multiple criteria" from within an array element:

```
db.chat.find({
 "user1": 1, 
 "messages": { 
   "$elemMatch": { "capty": "B" , "body": "hiii 1" }
 }
})
```

And the count:

```
db.chat.find({
 "user1": 1, 
 "messages": { 
   "$elemMatch": { "capty": "B" , "body": "hiii 1" }
 }
}).count()
```

That will match the correct documents and return their count.

Actual documents returned:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7662"),
        "user1" : 1,
        "user2" : 2,
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "capty" : "A",
                        "body" : "hiii 0"
                },
                {
                        "capty" : "B",
                        "body" : "hiii 1"
                },
                {
                        "capty" : "A",
                        "body" : "hiii 2"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7664"),
        "user1" : 1,
        "user2" : 4,
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "capty" : "A",
                        "body" : "hiii 0"
                },
                {
                        "capty" : "B",
                        "body" : "hiii 1"
                },
                {
                        "capty" : "B",
                        "body" : "hiii 24"
                }
        ]
}
```

The same "query" condition applies to aggregate [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) if you really want to use it there. But for a "count", it's faster to use the "cursor".